# Is it possible and prudent to combine these three SELECT statements?

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL tables:

```
LEVEL(lid)    USERS(uid,name,l_id)   USERS_G(u_id,r_id,flag)   REQUESTS(rid,status)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1              1  John   1         1  96   1                  96    0
  2              2  Peter  1         1  97   1                  97    0
  3              3  Helen  2         2  97   0                  98    0 
                                     3  97   0                  99    1 
                                     2  98   1
                                     1  98   0
                                     3  98   0
```

LEVEL to USERS 1:N, USERS to USERS_G 1:N, REQUESTS to USERS_G 1:N.

I want to select those records from REQUESTS which have a certain status and at the same time the users-holders of these requests-records have a certain level. Consider that a user is holder of a request if the corresponding flag in USERS_G equals 1. This is rather easy and is implemented as follows:

```
SELECT lid,rid,name FROM REQUESTS JOIN USERS_G 
        ON REQUESTS.rid = USERS_G.r_id AND flag=1 AND status='0'
        JOIN USERS 
        ON USERS_G.u_id=USERS.uid
        JOIN LEVEL 
        ON LEVEL.lid=USERS.l_id AND LEVEL.lid='1';
```

The results of the above query are:

```
1    96    John
1    97    John
1    98    Peter
```

So far, so good. Moreover, I want to find the number of records which are associated with any of the previous requests. In other words:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REQUESTS JOIN USERS_G 
        ON REQUESTS.rid = USERS_G.r_id
        WHERE REQUESTS.status='0' GROUP BY REQUESTS.rid;
```

namely

```
1
3
3
```

I haven't finished yet! I also want the corresponding names inside a string:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(USERS.name SEPARATOR '\n') FROM USERS,USERS_G,REQUESTS
WHERE uid=u_id AND r_id=rid AND status=0 GROUP BY rid;
```

As to make things a little bit more comprehensive I want the following results
with one query?

```
 Level       Rid   Holder Name       Count       Concat
---------------------------------------------------------------
 1            96      John              1          John
 1            97      John              3          John  Peter Helen
 1            98      Peter             3          John  Peter Helen
```

Is it feasible to achieve that? It is obvious this query has to be executed as fast as possible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not a bad effort, but, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to show select the `rid` in all 3 queries and joint the queries together. E.g. something like this:

```
SELECT r.*, counts.count, names.concat

FROM (
    SELECT lid,rid,name FROM REQUESTS JOIN USERS_G 
        ON REQUESTS.rid = USERS_G.r_id AND flag=1 AND status='0'
        JOIN USERS 
        ON USERS_G.u_id=USERS.uid
        JOIN LEVEL 
        ON LEVEL.lid=USERS.l_id AND LEVEL.lid='1' 
    ) AS r
JOIN (
    SELECT rid, COUNT(*) as count FROM REQUESTS JOIN USERS_G 
        ON REQUESTS.rid = USERS_G.r_id
        WHERE REQUESTS.status='0' GROUP BY REQUESTS.rid
    ) AS counts ON counts.rid = r.rid
JOIN (
    SELECT rid, GROUP_CONCAT(USERS.name SEPARATOR '\n') AS concat FROM USERS,USERS_G,REQUESTS
    WHERE uid=u_id AND r_id=rid AND status=0 GROUP BY rid;
    ) AS names ON names.rid = r.rid
```